# Cannot find function from imported module

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, vue.js, es6-modules

first of all thanks in advance for the feedback.
As I am new to es6 and vuejs I'm starting to have problems using imported Services module throughout the application. The end goal would be to move everything that uses Axios to one BaseService too.

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__services_AuthService__.a.getCurrentUser is not a function"
```

AuthService.js

```
import BaseService from './BaseService'

export default class AuthService {

  setCurretUser( user )
  {
    localStorage.setItem("currentUser", user);
  }

  getCurrentUser()
  {
    return localStorage.getItem("currenUser");
  }

}
```

App.vue

```
import Axios from 'axios'
import Navbar from './partials/Navbar'
import Sidebar from './partials/Sidebar'
import AuthService from '../services/AuthService'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Sidebar
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Component mounted.')
  },
  created() {
    Axios.get('api/user')
      .then(function (response) {
        AuthService.setCurrentUser(response.data);
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to use `AuthService` class as a container for methods, convert them to `static` so they can be called without instantiating the class (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Static_methods)

```
export default class AuthService {

  static setCurretUser( user )
  {
    localStorage.setItem("currentUser", user);
  }

  static getCurrentUser()
  {
    return localStorage.getItem("currenUser");
  }

}
```

Or you could also contain them in an object:

```
export default {

  setCurretUser( user )
  {
    localStorage.setItem("currentUser", user);
  },

  getCurrentUser()
  {
    return localStorage.getItem("currenUser");
  }

}
```

Comment: Or export them as named exports, e.g. `export function setCurrentUser(user){ ... }` and do `import * as AuthService from`

Comment: Wow, of course, I'm calling them statically. What would be the clean way to instantiate a class to be used in the .vue object.